# How do I decrypt, using Additional Authenticated Data, with Rust's AES-GCM?

Tags: rust, encryption, aes-gcm

The [documentation of AES-GCM](https://docs.rs/aes-gcm/0.10.2/aes_gcm/index.html#usage) only demonstrates decryption without [AAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Programming_interface).

I need to use this additional authenticated data, as my cipher text has been encrypted with it (in C and JavaScript implementations).

In Node.js/JavaScript, I do this with:

```
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', km, iv);
decipher.setAAD(aad);
decipher.setAuthTag(tag);
const plaintext = decipher.update(ciphertext);
return Buffer.concat([plaintext, decipher.final()]);
```

I've tried VS Code autocomplete on various Rust objects and not yet found any functions mentioning AAD.

- Is there a way to search for Rust functions including the string 'AAD', that is better than Googling?
- How do I decrypt my ciphertexts which use AAD?

Comment: It looks like you pack the ciphertext and aad in a `Payload` https://docs.rs/aead/0.5.2/aead/trait.Aead.html#tymethod.decrypt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When porting the NodeJS code, there are two things to keep in mind:

- In the NodeJS code ciphertext and tag are processed separately, in the Rust code they are processed concatenated (ciphertext|tag). The concatenation can be done explicitly in the NodeJS code during encryption, or alternatively in the Rust code during decryption.
- The AAD are to be passed together with the ciphertext/tag concatenation in a [`Payload`](https://docs.rs/aead/latest/aead/struct.Payload.html#) struct (as already noted in the comment).

Example (concatenation of ciphertext and tag in the Rust code):

```rust
use aes_gcm::{aead::{Aead, KeyInit, Payload}, Aes256Gcm, Nonce, Key}; 
use base64::{engine::general_purpose, Engine as _};
use std::str;

fn main() { 

    // Input data (e.g. Base64 encoded)
    let key_b64 = "gCOxqU/5JIUrEp5bZ+BSv0pqkV7fpC0sAtRLD6/alSc=";
    let nonce_b64 = "zGj7byavu/FF7XlC"; 
    let aad_b64 = "c29tZSBhZGRpdGlvbmFsIGRhdGEgdG8gYXV0aGVudGljYXRl"; // Base64 encoding of: "some additional data to authenticate"
    let ciphertext_b64 = "cJ/gL3Q+YDCbS69dkWWz3TBzmrxZiZ9arcxjMIgeoLZl4GQcYAgAvDxttg==";
    let tag_b64 = "4xjofRMg3fuUvpUTiKNquA==";
  
    // Base64 decode ciphertext and tag, concatenate both: ciphertext|tag 
    let ciphertext = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(&ciphertext_b64).unwrap();
    let tag = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(&tag_b64).unwrap();
    let ciphertext_tag = [ciphertext, tag].concat();

    // Base64 decode AAD
    let aad = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(&aad_b64).unwrap();
    //let aad = String::from("some additional data to authenticate").into_bytes(); // alternatively, if AAD are simply a string
    
    // Wrap ciphertext|tag and AAD in Payload struct
    let payload = Payload {
        msg: &ciphertext_tag[..],
        aad: &aad[..],
    };

    // Base64 decode key and nonce, import both
    let nonce = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(&nonce_b64).unwrap();
    let key = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(&key_b64).unwrap();
    let nonce = Nonce::from_slice(&nonce[..]);  
    let key = Key::<Aes256Gcm>::from_slice(&key[..]);

    // Decrypt
    let cipher = Aes256Gcm::new(&key);
    match cipher.decrypt(&nonce, payload) {
        Ok(decrypted) => println!("Decrypted data: {}", str::from_utf8(&decrypted).unwrap()), // Decrypted data: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Decryption error: {}", e),
    }
}
```

The posted NodeJS code gives the same result with the following input:

```js
var km = Buffer.from('gCOxqU/5JIUrEp5bZ+BSv0pqkV7fpC0sAtRLD6/alSc=', 'base64');
var iv = Buffer.from('zGj7byavu/FF7XlC', 'base64');
var aad = Buffer.from('c29tZSBhZGRpdGlvbmFsIGRhdGEgdG8gYXV0aGVudGljYXRl', 'base64');
var ciphertext = Buffer.from('cJ/gL3Q+YDCbS69dkWWz3TBzmrxZiZ9arcxjMIgeoLZl4GQcYAgAvDxttg==', 'base64');
var tag = Buffer.from('4xjofRMg3fuUvpUTiKNquA==', 'base64');
```